# Is there a way to exec a SP, check the result with an if statement and return the value, all within just one line?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I know this works but does anybody know of a way of doing all these in **one** line of code:

```
EXEC @ResultInt = NameofAStoredProcedure
IF @ResultInt <> 0
RETURN @ResultInt
```

LIKE:

```
-- I'm trying something like this but it does not work we want to do it all in
-- one line to do a Find-Replace throughout our code base
IF (EXEC @ResultInt = NameofAStoredProcedure) <> 0 RETURN ResultInt
```

Comment: [Should I use Tags in my question title ?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) ... No you should not.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in only "one line" of code? Whitespace isn't significant in TSQL, so you can put it all on one line if you want.

Comment: "Why do you need to do this in only "one line" of code?"  Weel, easier to read just for starters.  By far the #1 response to questions in the field of SQL is "why do you want to do that".  I wonder if anyone asking that question knows any other language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm getting something wrong, but why not simply removing the whitespaces?

```
EXEC @ResultInt = NameofAStoredProcedure IF @ResultInt <> 0 RETURN @ResultInt;
```

If all you want is to have it in one line for easier editing, that should work. You even could include the declaration of `@ResultInt`:

```
DECLARE @ResultInt int; EXEC @ResultInt = NameofAStoredProcedure IF @ResultInt <> 0 RETURN @ResultInt;
```

Tested with MS SQL 2005.

Comment: i would say the same. but you was faster :P

Comment: good idea but the problem is that our company has some coding standards and we pretty much have one statement per line since we have different pieces of logic (dynamic code, etc)

Comment: Ok I receive approval to deviate a little bit from our coding standard so I'm using this answer, simple answer, simple solution, I like it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT**. As noted this **doesn't** work*, but I'll leave it in place to show what you cannot do :)

Without chaining items all together onto one ugly line, the only way I can think of is to wrap the call in a Scalar Function.

But then it's not something you can re-use easily and will create allot of wrapper objects if your doing this allot. Is great way to keep code clean if your only doing this for one or two procedures, more then it just makes allot of objects to manage in the DB.

Example

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SPWrapper() RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @out int;
EXEC @out=NameOfStoredProcedure;
RETURN @out;
END
GO

-- Usage 
IF (SELECT dbo.SPWrapper() ) <> 0
```

Comment: Good idea, even though SQL Server allowed me to create the function it didn't let me execute the function that calls a stored procedure by saying: "Only functions and SOME extended stored procedures can be executed within a function"..

Comment: Ha, ok, I think I have even done this before and had that result too! I'll update the answer so others will remember better then I do.

Comment: No problem, I really liked that approach not sure why SQL Server would allow this only to "SOME" extended sprocs! :-)

Comment: It's due to the fact Scalar functions in TSQL are not supposed to have the ability to modify data. Since an SP can do that the query optimizer cannot reliably operate (or something like that). It can be made to work in a .NET CLR Function, but that is not practical unless you already deal with a CLR project on the server. Also probably totally goes outside acceptable practises by your team.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to crush everything down to one row to make mass find and replaces easier, 
I would recommend using [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to handle carriage returns and line feeds while maintaining code readability.  For instance, let's say you wanted to change "IF @ResultInt <> 0" to "IF @ResultInt <> 1" and add row "SET @ResultInt = 1", then do the following:

***ENABLE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS IN FIND AND REPLACE***

In Find and Replace in both Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio, expand the Find Options -> Select Use -> Select Regular expressions.

***FIND WHAT STATEMENT***

```
EXEC \@ResultInt = NameofAStoredProcedure\nIF \@ResultInt \<\> 0\nRETURN \@ResultInt
```

***REPLACE WITH STATEMENT***

```
EXEC \@ResultInt = NameofAStoredProcedure\nIF \@ResultInt \<\> 1\nSET \@ResultInt = 1\nRETURN \@ResultInt
```

***RESULTS***

```
EXEC @ResultInt = NameofAStoredProcedure
IF @ResultInt <> 1
SET @ResultInt = 1
RETURN @ResultInt
```